# comparison of mathematical formulas

Tags: algorithm, math, compare, simplify, java

I'm facing a small problem parsing and comparing mathematical formulas.

Suppose we have the following 3 formulas:

- `2*a+b*c`
- `j*i+e+e`
- `x+(y*z)+x`

We agree, the 3 formulas are equal.
How can we compare different formulas and know whether they are equal or not? 
Do you know java APIs that allow you to rewrite and simplify these formulas in order to compare them?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10169/how-to-search-for-a-formula-expression isn't directly relevant, but discusses the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This task is not trivial and requires an understanding of the parse trees. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree

The main idea is to build the parse tree of your expression and to normalize it, arrange the nodes in such a way that the order will be the same of "equal" expressions.

For instance, your first expression will parse as a sum (+) of two products (*), one of which involves a constant and a variable, and the other, two other variables.

The prefix traversal of the tree would be

```
+ * 2 a * b c
```

If you adopt the convention that a constant comes before a variable, and if you rename the variables,

```
+ * 2 V0 * V1 V2
```

will represent all expressions such as `a*2+d*f`, `f*a+2*b`... But not `2*a+a*c`, that has a repeated variable and should be `+ * 2 V0 * V0 V1`.

---

You are making things even harder by regrouping like terms (`e+e` becomes `2*e`). This can probably be achieved by preprocessing the parse tree and discover identical subtrees. In the given case

```
+ V2 V2
```

cane be seen as a sum of two equal formulas and be turned to

```
* 2 V2
```

before further processing.

---

I am not sure that the general case will be that easy.

Comment: if I manage to formalize and rewrite the same formulas with the same variables (V0, V1, V2...) I could subtract two formulas, and if they cancel each other this would mean that they are equal.